# "Official" time for other planets

Tags: planet, solar-system, time

I want to make clock that shows current time on different solar bodies. For that I need to know how to count time on those planets. Is there any official definition of times on other planets in our solar system? Brief google search did not help.

I am capable of implementing library for this myself but I wonder about current *state of the art* of time telling on other planets. So basically I want to know these things:

- Is there any official time standard?
- If so, where can I find it?
- If not, how should I approach this problem? Should I make something like Unix epoch at some time in the past for every planet?

Thanks for any tips.

EDIT: Ok, so on Mars, seconds, minutes and hours were made longer to keep 24-hour day. Is this viable to other planets as well? Venus aside for now :)

I was also thinking about keeping the hours the same, having days as long as many whole hours fits in them plus smaller compensation hours which would have length of (total_minutes_in_solar_day % 60). This concept is from David Weber novels, if you are familiar with them.

EDIT2: Based on discussion in the comments, I'll try to make some basic model that would be if possible applicable to any planetary body (thinking ahead :)). This is obviously not going to have any serious real world application but I would still like it to have some sense.

Thanks for your input, I will leave the question open for some more time if anyone wants to add their opinion.

Comment: Let's take a look at the other planets: Mercury has only one apparent day every two years from the surface and Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, and Neptune are gas giants with no surface. Do you want to consider dwarf planets and moons?

Comment: Really, it is hard to give you much more specific advice without knowing the application for your timekeeping system. Timekeeping is pointless without an application.

Comment: Unix time is defined using seconds, and seconds are the same everywhere (up to relativity). Seconds are SI units. I would advise against touching seconds, even if it means you don't have an integer number of them in a day. If you really want to, you could have units very close in size, but be wary of naming them in a way that can get a decent SI abbreviation. Also, don't use them in physics!

Comment: @JanDvorak yes, that's probably good point, thanks!

Comment: @called2voyage my application is the clock that would show current time on other planets. I think it would be cool thing to have on your wall to baffle visits :) other than that I just want to satisfy my need to code something.

Comment: @lsrom So, assuming we had a colony on each of the planets, you want to know how time would be measured there?

Comment: @called2voyage Yes. I wanted some "official" standard for this so it wouldn't be just something I made up, but apparently there is no such thing.

Comment: Don't forget there's no single "current time" on Earth either. There is GMT, but not many people actually use it except to determine offsets when converting from one timezone to another.

Comment: @JanDvorak Well, I think I will deal with that when I dealt with how many hours are in the day :) When I have working time model for planets, I can easily make timezone functions.

Comment: @lsrom I updated my answer.

Comment: Rotation periods of individual solar bodies can be found on the Internet. How you draw lines on these barren surfaces is up to you.

Comment: @JanDvorak Actually, astronomers have already defined a "prime meridian" for most planets + have even created a scheme for doing so with future discoveries: https://astropedia.astrogeology.usgs.gov/download/Docs/WGCCRE/WGCCRE2009reprint.pdf

Comment: @barrycarter nice. Though, do I understand correctly the procedure is essentially just "pick a significant point on the surface that is going to stay there, and draw the prime meridian through it", with no specification of what that object should be except that it's significant?

Comment: My mistake. I meant for dwarf planets, minor planets, their satellites, and comets the note on pages 16-17: "The choice of prime meridian is potentially arbitrary, but there is precedent (e.g. with (433) Eros) for choosing it so it aligns with the longest axis (or minimum moment of inertia, if this can be estimated).".

Comment: @barrycarter Understood, thanks. Do you happen to know where the prime meridian would be if determined for Earth this way?

Comment: @JanDvorak I think they intentionally don't do it that way for planets because, even though planets are ellipsoids (not spheres), they tend to be fairly uniform ellipsoids and each line of longitude on planets is almost exactly the same length. In other words, the "flattening" of most planets is an equatorial bulge, and occurs in such a way that lines of longitude remain the same length.

Comment: It's a **straightforward** and **good** question.  **"Is there any official definition of times on other planets in our solar system?"**

Comment: Related question: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26556/how-are-mars-years-counted

Comment: @JohnDvorak From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time "English speakers often use GMT as a synonym for Coordinated Universal Time(UTC). For navigation, it is considered equivalent to UT1 (the modern form of mean solar time at 0° longitude); but this meaning can differ from UTC by up to 0.9 s. The term GMT should not thus be used for technical purposes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time on Mars is measured in [sols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timekeeping_on_Mars).

[Venus](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18655/58) could be a little trickier, depending on your application.

I'm not aware of any timekeeping system for any other planets. There hasn't been a need for one yet. So, again depending on your application, you could come up with various different possible schemes.

---

Speculation (based on the OP's input regarding application):

- Mercury - because of the length of the day, I doubt would-be colonists would measure time in days. They would probably use Earth time (because of communications) and also keep track of Mercury years.
- Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune - no colonization, no timekeeping

Comment: Well,  us *Terrans*  use sols for Martian time.  What the aboriginals on Mars use is as yet unknown.

Comment: On the surface of Mercury, 1 day = 2 years = 176 days.   That would likely be defined as seasons.   Earth time, as called2voyage points out, would probably be easiest for Mercury, as there's no celestial time that works on a human schedule, unlike Mars, which has a very convenient, 24 hour and 37 minute days.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the right coefficients of Equation of Time for other planets, which mainly depends on orbit eccentricty and orbit inclination.
Here you find a full demonstration of how to get a generic EOT for any planet:

http://www.ifpan.edu.pl/firststep/aw-works/fsII/mul/mueller.pdf

It's highly complex math which I have yet to fully understand...

This page provide details on algorithm for timekeeping on Mars:
https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/mars24/help/algorithm.html

This page containts a huge amount of data, formulas and explanations about timekeeping on other planets:

http://pbarbier.com/eqtime/eqtime.html

And we are also discussing this topic in this other question (without an answer yet):

[Timekeeping on other celestial bodies than Earth](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/38362/timekeeping-on-other-celestial-bodies-than-earth/38378?noredirect=1#comment76373_38378)

Apart from this, to "keep the time" on any planet you need to know your angular distance from planet prime meridian (passing through Greenwich on Earth), but this is just the last, and easiest, step. The actually changeling thing is determining the angular position of prime meridian: once you know it, there are plenty of sites providing algorithms and libraries to determine the position of a planet around the Sun at a specific time: joining the two data (prime meridian angle and planet angle) you will be able to determine angle of sun w.r.t. prime meridian.

Lacking specific libraries/formulas to calculate local time on any planet, you can temporary use Nasa Horizons to retrieve Altidue and Azimuth of Sun over a specific location on any planet using [this query/URL](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons_batch.cgi?batch=1&COMMAND=%270%27&CENTER=%27coord@499%27&OBJ_DATA=%27yes%27&MAKE_EPHEM=%27yes%27&TABLE_TYPE=%27OBSERVER%27&REF_PLANE=%27ECLIPTIC%27&COORD_TYPE=%27GEODETIC%27&SITE_COORD=%270,0,0%27&START_TIME=%272020/8/20%2014:36%27&STOP_TIME=%272020/8/21%2014:36%27&STEP_SIZE=%271h%27&QUANTITIES=%274%27&FIXED_QUANTITIES=%27Custom%27&REF_SYSTEM=%27J2000%27&OUT_UNITS=%27KM-S%27&VECT_TABLE=%273%27&VECT_CORR=%27NONE%27&CAL_FORMAT=%27CAL%27&ANG_FORMAT=%27HMS%27&APPARENT=%27AIRLESS%27&TIME_TYPE=%27UTC%27&TIME_DIGITS=%27MINUTES%27&RANGE_UNITS=%27AU%27&SUPPRESS_RANGE_RATE=%27no%27&SKIP_DAYLT=%27no%27&EXTRA_PREC=%27yes%27&CSV_FORMAT=%27yes%27&VEC_LABELS=%27yes%27&ELM_LABELS=%27yes%27&TP_TYPE=%27ABSOLUTE%27&R_T_S_ONLY=%27NO%27&CA_TABLE_TYPE=%27STANDARD%27).

Change "499" to other numbers for other planets: 199 = Mercury, 299 = Venus,.... Change SITE_COORD parameter to desired location (lon, lat, altidue): SITE_COORD='0,0,0'

Note: single quote ' is coded as %27 in the url.